# C++ Programming, having trouble programming finding velocity and distance

Tags: c++, physics

Hey I'm a beginner taking an intro to C++ class, and this is my first assignment. I posted this a couple of days ago but I still am somewhat lost. I have to use the formulas: d=v0*t + 1/2*g*t^2, and v= v0 + g*t. where v0 stays constant at 0 and g also stays constant at 9.807 m/s^2. I keep getting one error which is "expected unqualified-id before "{" token" on the first { and cannot seem to fix them, and im sure this code is incorrect, so can you help me figure this out?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const float GRAVITY = 9.807, INITIALVELOCITY = 0;
int seconds;


{
cout << "Please enter the time in seconds." << endl;
cin >> seconds;
}  //end function Time

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
float distance, velocity, seconds;
void getSeconds (void);

cout.setf (ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);

cin >> seconds;
while (seconds > 0) {

distance = INITIALVELOCITY * seconds + (0.5 * GRAVITY * pow(seconds, 2));
velocity = INITIALVELOCITY + (GRAVITY * seconds);

cout.precision (0);
cout << endl << "WHEN THE TIME IS" << seconds << "SECONDS THE DISTANCE"
"TRAVELED IS" << distance << "METERS THE VELOCITY IS" << velocity <<
"METERS PER SECOND.";
cout. precision(1);
cout<< seconds << distance << velocity << endl << endl;

}

system ("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} //end main
```

Comment: It looks like you are having trouble with basic function declaration and usage. You will probably find it more helpful to go back and re-read any textbook assignments.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>    {
>       cout << "Please enter the time in seconds." << endl;
>       cin >> seconds;
>    }  //end function Time
> ```

Isn't a thing. It's a block of code appearing outside of any function. That's not possible in c++, since every block of code needs a function to enter it. The starting entering point is constituted from the

```
int main() {
}
```

function block.

And you already have

```
cin >> seconds;
```

there.

---

Are you actually asking about how to factoring that statement out to a function? Then the answer probably is

```
   int getTime() {
      cout << "Please enter the time in seconds." << endl;
      cin >> seconds;
      return seconds;
    }  //end function Time
```

and in `main()` write

```
   while ((getTime()) > 0) {
       // ...
   }
```

Not that I'd really recommend organizing your code like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
cout << "Please enter the time in seconds." << endl;
cin >> seconds;
}  //end function Time
```

I guess this is supposed to be a function? If so, give it a name...

Answer (score 0):

Now it works... don't copy from books, books always leave things out to be defined or specified... Always try to write the code yourself. If you write the code yourself, then [Structure of a program](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/) go true this again ;)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const float GRAVITY = 9.807, INITIALVELOCITY = 0;
int seconds;

int time()
 {
   int seconds = 0;
   cout << "Please enter the time in seconds." << endl;
   cin >> seconds;
   return seconds;
 }  //end function Time

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
   float distance, velocity, seconds;
   seconds = time();

   while (seconds > 0) {

    distance = INITIALVELOCITY * seconds + (0.5 * GRAVITY * pow(seconds, 2));
    velocity = INITIALVELOCITY + (GRAVITY * seconds);

    cout.precision (0);
    cout << endl << "WHEN THE TIME IS" << seconds << "SECONDS THE DISTANCE"
"TRAVELED IS" << distance << "METERS THE VELOCITY IS" << velocity <<
"METERS PER SECOND.";
    cout. precision(1);
    cout<< seconds << distance << velocity << endl << endl;
    seconds--;
}

 system ("PAUSE");
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} //end main
```